# Java Wrapping Generic Class That Could Return Any Type

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a generic class that represent the various parameters in our application. Parameters can be booleans, integers, decimals, date, longs, strings, etc. I've created the following class to represent that.

```
public class Parameter<T> {

    private final String paramName;
    private final Category category;
    private final SubCategory subCategory;
    private final T defaultValue;
    private final Class<T> type;

    public Parameter(String paramName, Category category, SubCategory subCategory, T defaultValue, Class<T> type) {
        this.paramName = paramName;
        this.category = category;
        this.subCategory = subCategory;
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getParamName() {
        return paramName;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public SubCategory getSubCategory() {
        return subCategory;
    }

    public T getDefaultValue() {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    public Class<T> getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}
```

This class is being wrapped by an Enum like so.

```
public enum Parameters {

    HEARTBEAT_SERVICE_INTERVAL(new Parameter<Integer>("HeartbeatInterval", Category.SYSTEM, SubCategory.HEALTH_CHECK, 300000, Integer.class));

    private Parameter<?> parameter;

    Parameters(Parameter<?> parameter) {
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }

    public Parameter<?> getParameter() {
        return this.parameter;
    }
}
```

I have a parameter service which takes the ENUM as an argument. I need to know the type of the generic T of parameter and do some logic depending on that. However I'm struggling to determine the type at runtime. The getParameter method of the parameter service needs to return a generic type because its going to return the value of the parameter if its found, otherwise use the default value on the Parameter class.

```
public <T> T getParameter(Parameters parameter, Class<T> clazz) {

    // do something to figure out what type T is ????
}
```

EDIT:

The intended usage of the code is the following.

```
// get a String valued parameter
String text = parameterService.getParameterValue(Parameters.SOME_TEXT_PARAM);

// get a boolean valued parameter
Boolean isEnabled = parameterService.getParameterValue(SERVICE_ENABLED);

// etc
```

Comment: `I'm struggling to determine the type at runtime.` See [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Comment: The type of T is passed as argument: `clazz`. So I don't really understand the question. What is this method supposed to do? Suppose I call it with `String s = getParameter(Parameters.HEARTBEAT_SERVICE_INTERVAL, String.class)`. What should the method do?

Comment: What you want cannot be done with an enum.  However, you can write a “fake” enum (a regular class with public static constants and private constructor), as Java did with classes like [StandardSocketOptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/StandardSocketOptions.html).  This would allow you to give each constant a different generic type argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of type erasure, the only way to communicate the class, is to pass one as a parameter -- but you are already doing this:

```
public <T> T getParameter(Parameters parameter, Class<T> clazz)
```

At compile time, Java knows that `T` is `clazz`. At runtime, Java doesn't know this, but it doesn't matter.

The following works:

```
Object foo = new Foo();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T getFoo(Class<T> clazz) {
    return (T) foo;
}

...

Foo f = getFoo(Foo.class);
```

... and is quite a common pattern. Essentially you're using the `Class<T>` parameter to bridge between compile time when generics are meaningful, and runtime when they are not.

It's your responsibility to ensure that the casts don't screw up at runtime, hence the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. The compiler can't do it for you: this would still compile if `foo` where declared as `Object foo = new Bar()`.

It's not much of a leap from this to:

```
Map<String,Object> parameters;

...

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T getParameter(String key, Class<T> clazz) {
    return (T) parameters.get(key);
}
```

You can also use `clazz.isInstance()` to guard against runtime class cast exceptions:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T getParameter(String key, Class<T> clazz) {
    Object o = parameters.get(key)
    if(clazz.isInstance(o)) {
        return (T) o;
    } else {
        return null; // or something better...
    }
}
```

You could also do things like `if(clazz.equals(Bar.class)`.

In some circumstances you might need to be a bit more sophisticated and use `Class<? extends T> clazz` -- don't worry about this too much until it hits you, unless you're writing library code, in which case you should have unit tests for

```
parameters.add("x", new SubclassOfFoo()); 
Foo foo = parameters.get("x", Foo.class);
```

Note, this whole approach only works for object types. You'll need to use `Integer` not `int`. In practice autoboxing makes this painless.

Comment: What if inside I need to do some different logic based on the Class<T> clazz passed in. Say they call it with Foo.class I need to do something, and if its Bar.class I need to do something slightly different. I don't seem to be able to do instanceof checks of a class say against Boolean

Comment: @greyfox added something about `isInstance`. Look at the Javadoc for `Class` for the full range of things you can do with `clazz`.

Answer (score 0):

here codes are from the ibatis, the TypeReference would help.

1. make you Parameter class be abstract
2. using Parameter p = new Parameter(){}
3. you can get the type by calling p.getRawType();

   ```
   /**
   * References a generic type.
   *
   * @param <T> the referenced type
   * @since 3.1.0
   * @author Simone Tripodi
   */
   public abstract class TypeReference<T> {

   private final Type rawType;

   protected TypeReference() {
       rawType = getSuperclassTypeParameter(getClass());
   }

   Type getSuperclassTypeParameter(Class<?> clazz) {
       Type genericSuperclass = clazz.getGenericSuperclass();
       if (genericSuperclass instanceof Class) {
       // try to climb up the hierarchy until meet something useful
       if (TypeReference.class != genericSuperclass) {
           return getSuperclassTypeParameter(clazz.getSuperclass());
       }

       throw new TypeException("'" + getClass() + "' extends TypeReference but misses the type parameter. "
           + "Remove the extension or add a type parameter to it.");
       }

       Type rawType = ((ParameterizedType) genericSuperclass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
       // TODO remove this when Reflector is fixed to return Types
       if (rawType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
       rawType = ((ParameterizedType) rawType).getRawType();
       }

       return rawType;
   }

   public final Type getRawType() {
       return rawType;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return rawType.toString();
   }

   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Well, if its any type, then you essentially have an `Object` at runtime; you just need to ascertain your method for casting used variables. You'll need to pass a type token which can resolve the type at runtime. Since your `Parameter` has that, you can use it inside the parameter class:

```
public <R> R get() { //<R> R, so we can return any type, invalid types will CCE
    //double cast unnecessary, but left here because it's simplified code
    return (R) this.getType().cast(/* retrieved data */); //danger: removes type safety!
}

//Elsewheres, while losing safety, can be assigned direct:
int interval = Parameters.HEARTBEAT_SERVICE_INTERVAL.getParameter().get();
```

However, that's probably a far cry from what you want. Unfortunately you start to hit the realm of how you want to manually ensure that type safety, as you begin to hit the edge of what Java generics support. The way I handled it is through an `#as` method which would cast and check types/collections etc for me. You can see an example [linked here](https://github.com/Codelanx/CodelanxCommons/blob/master/src/main/java/com/codelanx/commons/config/ConfigFile.java#L40-L84). If done similarly here, it would look like:

```
int interval = Parameters.HEARTBEAT_SERVICE_INTERVAL.as(int.class); //int type token
```

Comment: `int.class` is valid, as is `Integer.class`. It's a simple type token.

Comment: I didn't know that. Cool